# Difference between Viewport Size and Screen Size

Tags: responsive, screen, viewport

I want to make my Web Page responsive for different devices. I can check my Web Page with the"Responsive Design Mode" tool of Inspector in Firefox. But this tool only have mobile device options.

I have asked for what are the most common "viewport sizes" for tablet, laptops and desktops and i have been redirected to the page https://gs.statcounter.com/screen-resolution-stats/desktop/worldwide.

But it shows the most common "screen sizes" not "viewport sizes". For example, one common screen size for desktop is 1920px X 1080px. I have this monitor and if i visit the page https://whatismyviewport.com/ it tell me that my monitor has:

- Viewport size: 1920px X 919px
- Screen size: 1920px X 1080 px

So both sizes are different thing.

I suppose, not sure, to create media queries the important thing is viewport size.

Then what is the difference between viewport size and screen size?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Your screen size is the number of pixels in the total width and height of your computer.
The size of your viewport is the number of pixels in the browser window on your screen, so it is quite normal for the viewport to be smaller than the screen size.

Edit: I found [this article](https://yesviz.com/article.php) for a better understanding.

Comment: Thanks Clement. I understand you, do you know if there is any way to find out the viewport size from screen size??

Comment: I don't understand what you want to get, but if you want the viewport, you can simply get it with CSS with the unit `vw`. Example: `width: 100vw` defines the width to fill the viewport.

Comment: I am interested to know the most common viewport sizes for mobile, tablet, laptop and desktop to try my Web Page on them (using Responsive Design Mode tool of the Firefox Inspector), and then apply the media queries that are neccesary.

Comment: You can find this on [this page](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/css-media-queries-breakpoints-media-types-standard-resolutions-and-more/)